# What happens when I use the map flags?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are a number of maps in Skyrim, mostly in the Jarls' palaces or various camps.  All of these maps have flags placed in them to mark Imperial or Stormcloak territories.  When I "use" one of these flags, a message pops up saying "Map Updated".  However, at this stage in the game, my map is such a mess I wouldn't be able to really tell if anything changed on it or not.

Can someone tell me exactly what sort of update is being done here?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the Jarl's map in the Dragonreach?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36816/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-jarls-map-in-the-dragonreach)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It simply shows you that city on the map as an unexplored location. It is a good way for new players to populate their maps with major cities and towns.

Comment: It's annoying that it says "Map Updated" even for places that are already on your map.